# Pandas TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I'm analyzing students' performances and I want to count the percentage of students whose math score is higher than 80, I casted the scores from string to int, but I still get an error. Why?

```
    import pandas as pd 

    df = pd.read_csv('Data/StudentsPerformance.csv')
    df['math_score'] = df['math_score'].astype(int)
    filt = (df['math_score'] >= 80)
    higherthan80 = df.loc[filt]
    respond_count = df.gender.count()
    part = higherthan80 / respond_count
```

Comment: Use "divide and conquer" to find the row that causes the error.

Comment: @DYZ  the last line causes the error, it says unsupported operand types, but they're both integers.

Comment: You're dividing all the columns in the dataframe, not just the `math_score` column.

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to calculate a percentage of anything. Why are you dividing everything by the counts of each gender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are trying to divide the whole dataframe to the respond_count. Try to take only the math_score field.

```py
higherthan80 = df.loc[df['math_score'] >= 80, "math_score"]
```